# Google map is not zooming in & marker is not showing on page load

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am facing issue with Google map. It is not properly displaying with marker on page load. It appears to display properly with marker when we zoom in on displayed map.

Any help appreciated.

This is javascript code :-

```
var GoogleMap = function(canvas, address)
{
    var _parent = this;

    this.location = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);

    var options = 
    {
        center: this.location,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControlOptions: 
        {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER
        },
        streetViewControl: false
    };

    this.map = new google.maps.Map(canvas, options);

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) 
    {
        if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
            return;

        _parent.location = results[0].geometry.location;

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
        {
            map: _parent.map,
            position: _parent.location
        }); 

        _parent.resize();
    });
};

GoogleMap.prototype.resize = function() 
{
    google.maps.event.trigger(this.map, "resize");

    this.map.setCenter(this.location);
}

var Maps = function(classes)
{

    var _parent = this;

    _parent.maps = new Array();

    classes.each(function()
    {
        _parent.maps.push(new GoogleMap($(this).get(0), $(this).attr("data-address")));  
    });
};

Maps.prototype.resize = function() 
{
    for (var cnt = 0; cnt < this.maps.length; cnt++) 
    {
        this.maps[cnt].resize();
    }
};

var maps;

$(window).load(function()
{
     maps = new Maps($(".gMapsCanvas"));
});
```

This is HTML code :-

```
<div class="gMapsCanvas" data-address="Address,City,State,Country"></div>
```

Comment: It's working for me, what address did you provide?

Comment: This is one of example address (3209 West Smith Valley Road, Greenwood, IN) .. There is no error in console.

Comment: Well I update my exemble with this address and it works, did you test my example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working fine to me.
What address did you provide.  Do you have errors in the console?

Copy this exemple in a plain `.html` file and you will see it works. Then figure out what is different in your entire page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    
    <title>Getting Zoom Demo</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body{ height: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        .gMapsCanvas{ height: 100%; width: 100%; min-width:500px; min-height:300px; }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <label id="display-zoom-label">

        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="gMapsCanvas" data-address="3209 West Smith Valley Road, Greenwood, IN"></div>
    <script>
        var GoogleMap = function (canvas, address) {
            var _parent = this;

            this.location = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);

            var options =
            {
                center: this.location,
                zoom: 15,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                mapTypeControlOptions:
                {
                    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
                    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER
                },
                streetViewControl: false
            };

            this.map = new google.maps.Map(canvas, options);

            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
                    return;

                _parent.location = results[0].geometry.location;

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
                {
                    map: _parent.map,
                    position: _parent.location
                });

                _parent.resize();
            });
        };

        GoogleMap.prototype.resize = function () {
            google.maps.event.trigger(this.map, "resize");

            this.map.setCenter(this.location);
        }

        var Maps = function (classes) {

            var _parent = this;

            _parent.maps = new Array();

            classes.each(function () {
                _parent.maps.push(new GoogleMap($(this).get(0), $(this).attr("data-address")));
            });
        };

        Maps.prototype.resize = function () {
            for (var cnt = 0; cnt < this.maps.length; cnt++) {
                this.maps[cnt].resize();
            }
        };

        var maps;

        $(window).load(function () {
            maps = new Maps($(".gMapsCanvas"));
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this code.I have tested this example & its working fine.  My map is within 250px width & 250px height. When I use 100% width/height, I have found some portion of map is empty.

Comment: if the div is resized after the `map` is initialized you have to trigger `google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize')` That will fill up the empty space.